# How to display multiple creatives within one Ad Unit from one Line item with Google DFP

Tags: google-dfp, ads, double-click-advertising

I'm struggling with Google DFP. I can't figure out, how to show multiple creatives from one Ad unit. For example, I have `sidebar_1` Ad unit, and I want to target here `sidebar_1` house line item, and in this line item are five image creatives. I want to display all these five creatives and have this Ad unit responsive with his height to height of this creatives. See picture:

[image]

I would like to do it with Single asynchronous request and Safeframe containers.

Thank you for any suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I spent a lot of time to get answer to this question, and result is that it's not possible.

I came up with other solution, it's here as second solution [Google DFP - Resize SafeFrame custom creative outer Iframe container from inside (expand ad)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46144151/google-dfp-resize-safeframe-custom-creative-outer-iframe-container-from-inside/46144152#46144152). I will add there as many images as i want and iframe will expand/shrink to fit.